# Emulator issues

Tags: android, android-emulator

I apologize for the simplicity of my question, but is there a way to select which emulator your Android Application Project runs in? I'm running this in Eclipse

I thought it might have been specified in the activity_main.xml

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
```

but it clearly wasn't there. I ask this because I've noticed that some emulators have an email app on them while others don't, and the one emulator that works for my app is the one I made when I created the project

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?

Comment: The emulator used is a function of your IDE, it has nothing to do with your code.  Which emulators are you talking about which have email?

Comment: One of the emulators that had email I found was: NexusS Android 2.2 Platform 2.2 API Level 8

Answer (score 0):

If you are coding with Eclipse, you can follow this procedure :

->Right click on your project 
-> Run As 
-> Run  Configurations... 
-> Then in the list in the left select under Android Application your application name 
-> Go to the tab called Target in the panel in the right
Then you will be able here to select the emulator you want your application runs in.

Comment: Hmm, the only one that shows up as compatible is the one I started with, is there a way I can change this? Perhaps it has to do with me selecting the highest API I could find when I started?